# About vuetify v-data table pagination

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-data-table

[image]

Is it possible to modify v-data-table pagination?

In this v-data-table pagination section(next,previous button).Am trying to give functions to this next and previous pagination button.
But i don't know how to modify this pagination section in v-data-table!

Actually am trying to modify v-data-table to connect pagination with back end response.
But i don't get it.

```
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="userDetails" :search="search" :items-per-page="perPage"
    :pagination.sync="pagination"   :server-items-length="totalUsers" class="elevation-1"
    >

    <template v-slot:[`item.type`]="{ item }">
      <div v-if="item.type == 1">
        <v-icon>mdi-account-circle</v-icon>
        Google User
      </div>
      <div v-if="item.type == 0">
        <v-icon>mdi-account-box</v-icon>
        Normal User

      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.status`]="{ item }">
      <div v-if="item.status == 1">
        <v-icon style="color:green">mdi-checkbox-blank-circle </v-icon>
        Active
      </div>
      <div v-if="item.status == 0">
        <v-icon style="color:red">mdi-checkbox-blank-circle </v-icon>

        Inactive
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.action`]="{ item }">
      <div v-if="item.status == 1">
        <v-btn style="    width: 118px;" color="red" class="white--text" v-on:click="Active(item.id)">

          De-Activate
        </v-btn>

      </div>
      <div v-if="item.status == 0">

        <v-btn style="    width: 118px;" color="green" class="white--text" v-on:click="deActive(item.id)">
          Activate</v-btn>

      </div>

    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Script method below

```
async getUser() {

  http.get("/loggedInUser?page=").then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    console.log("ee", response.data)
    this.userDetails = response.data.users.data
    this.totalUsers = response.data.users.total
    this.perPage = response.data.users.per_page
    console.log("qq", this.totalUsers)
    
    this.userDetailss = this.userDetails.map((item) => item.status);
    console.log("1122222", this.userDetailss);
    // this.userStatus=response.data.users.data.status
    // console.log("dd",this.userStatus)
    console.log("ww", this.userDetails);

  });
},
```

I want to add `perPage` to an API endpoint  ("/loggedInUser?page=") when the pagination button is clicked.

Comment: Can you please explain your question a bit more by adding code info, images, use case, etc.?

Comment: Edited question can you please check it

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do. Do you just need to call a function when the user changes the page? If so, just use the [`@pagination` event](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-pagination).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can bind a function to changes to pagination with the [`update:page`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-update:page) event:

```html
<v-data-table
  ...
  @update:page="page => onUpdatePageHandler(page)"
>
```

It sounds like you want to realize external pagination, in which case you might be better off listening to [`update:options`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-update:options):

```html
<v-data-table
  ...
  @update:options="loadUsersWithOptions"
>
```

and

```
async loadUsersWithOptions({page, itemsPerPage, sortBy, sortDesc}) {
  const url = "/loggedInUser"
  const params = {page, itemsPerPage, sortBy, sortDesc}
  const response = await http.get(url, params) // don't know if you can pass params to your http directely, maybe you need to build the url manually
  const users = response.data.users
  ...
},
```

Alternatively, instead of using the events directly, you can `.sync` to data properties and watch changes to those. This is described in the documentation as [external pagination](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-pagination). While it is just an extra step to do the same as above, it allows you to manage the individual states more cleanly.